# Ubuntu 20.04 LTS Server : Error Opening File : Permission Denied

Tags: server, permissions, mount, files

I am attempting to upload a file to IPFS from a mounted hard drive and keep getting this error that says permission denied. You can see the permissions below and I should have access.

```
ubuntu@ubuntu:/mnt/torrents/completed$ sudo ipfs add '2616 images from huble space telescope.zip'
Error: open 2616 images from huble space telescope.zip: permission denied
```

```
ubuntu@ubuntu:/mnt/torrents/completed$ ls -l '2616 images from huble space telescope.zip'
-rwxrwxr-x 1 ubuntu ubuntu 77208213702 Sep  7 19:42 '2616 images from huble space telescope.zip'
```

```
ubuntu@ubuntu:/mnt$ ls -l torrents/
total 36
drwxr-xr-x  2 ubuntu ubuntu  4096 Jan 19 20:12 backups
drwxrwxrwt 13 ubuntu ubuntu  4096 Jan 19 20:12 completed
drwxr-xr-x 11 ubuntu ubuntu  4096 Jan 19 20:12 downloading
drwxrwxr-x  8 ubuntu ubuntu  4096 Sep  9 04:16 library
drwx------  2 ubuntu ubuntu 16384 Sep  4 22:39 lost+found
drwxr-xr-x  2 ubuntu ubuntu  4096 Sep  5 03:29 watch
```

```
ubuntu@ubuntu:/$ ls -l /mnt
total 4
drwxrwxr-x  8 ubuntu ubuntu  4096 Sep  8 01:45 torrents
```

I tried updating the `fstab`

```
LABEL=writable  /        ext4   defaults        0 1
LABEL=system-boot       /boot/firmware  vfat    defaults         0         1
/dev/sda1       /mnt/torrents   ext4    auto,user,rw    0 1
```

No change

This is causing major delays for two large projects.

Answer (score 0):

This issue was due to the the fact that I used a snap installation of ipfs `sudo snap install ipfs` which is restricted in scope by the nature of being a snap package. see [GitIssue](https://github.com/ipfs/go-ipfs/issues/7872#issuecomment-765033899)

In order to solve this I removed my installation of ipfs and reinstalled with  `sudo snap install ipfs --classic`